# How to reuse dataset in that stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

First, I need to get a dataset then I want to use that dataset more then one time.

```
   SELECT @FullTimeEmpResult =
   ( select * from emp where type="FullTime"
   );

 SELECT * from @FullTimeEmpResult where salary >5000;

 SELECT * from @FullTimeEmpResult where YearOfExperience> 5;
```

how I can do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just run both of those queries against `emp`? What actual problem are you solving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i would do without knowing the table structure.

Otherwise I might create the temporary table with the correct columns first, and insert in it afterwards (and not use select * to insert but instead select the needed columns from the emp table).

I used a temporary table instead of a table variable as to (in most cases) improve query performance.

```
 SELECT *
 INTO  #FullTimeEmpResult
 FROM emp WHERE TYPE='FullTime';


 SELECT * FROM #FullTimeEmpResult WHERE salary >5000;

 SELECT * FROM #FullTimeEmpResult WHERE YearOfExperience> 5;

 DROP TABLE #FullTimeEmpResult;
```

Comment: Can I do without a temporary table?